# Gradle task failed with exit code 1

Tags: flutter, error-handling, runtime-error

[image: error in cmd]

this is happening when running the flutter default app.

build is failing with an exception.
in the img it may be showing evaluating :app but now it is also showing problem occured evaluating project android.

Comment: have you tried changed the minCompileSdk to 21 and compileSdkVersion 33

Comment: How to do this can u please tell me

Comment: Did you have still this error?

Comment: Yes i still do have it